# How to set wildcard DNS record for Azure Virtual Machine w Linux?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, azure, reverse-proxy, azure-dns

I'm trying to deploy [WorkAdventure](https://github.com/thecodingmachine/workadventure) for test in an Azure Linux Virtual Machine with Linux, and access it from the internet.

For this I found [here #794 (comment)](https://github.com/thecodingmachine/workadventure/issues/794#issuecomment-797475549) a reference to a [good documentation](https://wiki.techinc.nl/Work-Adventure/install)  from insensitiveclod from technic.
I followed that guide, and did most of the steps in an Azure VM with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, dynamic IP address and with a DNS name like `mytestwa.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com`

I did:

- Create Azure VM with Linux
- Create Azure IP Address (public address and DNS name) and assigned to Azure VM
- Set up docker environment and network setup
- Set up Traefik (and coturn) seperately from jitsi/workadventure
- Set up WorkAdventure
- Set up Jitsi

Still, I can't test anything ([Traefik](https://github.com/traefik/traefik), [WorkAdventure](https://github.com/thecodingmachine/workadventure), or [JITSI](https://github.com/jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet)) because I don't know how could I achieve this step from the guide:
***"Set a wildcard DNS-record for `*.whatever.your.domain.is` to the publicly reachable IP of the machine you want to host it on. Using a CNAME record works fine. It might be good to set TTL to 5mins at first. (create DNS wildcard or each DNS entry for every services `xyz.whatever.your.domain.is`)"***

Hence, WorkAdventure will need to use subdomains (`play.*`, `pusher.*`, `meet.*`, etc.) and I can't access any of this (neither on `mytestwa.northeurope.cloudapp.azure` or `somefreedomain.tk`):

- admin.mytestwa.northeurope.cloudapp.azure
- play.mytestwa.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
- meet.mytestwa.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
- play.somefreedomain.tk
- ...somefreedomain.tk

Setting the wildcard DNS record for `*.mytestwa.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com` to the publicly reachable IP or to the DNS name should be done from Azure Portal or from the Azure VM Linux shell?

I managed to create a free Custom domain in freenom.com `somefreedomain.tk`.
This is what i have in freenom management panel as DNS settings.

Still don't know how to proceed, because when I try to add another record in DNS settings as * CNAME 3600 ...cloudapp.azure.com i receive the error: "Wild cards are not allowed!"

Does anyone have any idea and could help me, please?

I created an Azure resource IP Address and assigned to my Azure VM.
As can be seen in the attached picture, I also tried to Configure that Azure IP Address and Create an alias record in Azure DNS with an Azure resource DNS zone (named <strike>`dns.zone`</strike> `somefreedomain.tk`) but, still doesn't work, and my knowledge is limited regarding to DNS and subdomains stuff.

Any help or suggestions are more than welcomed!
Thank you very much!

I don't have enough reputation to put other links or images, so i'll leave [the link of the initial SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68934896/how-to-set-wildcard-dns-record-for-azure-virtual-machine-w-linux).

Answer (score 0):

Azure DNS supports wildcard records. Wildcard records get returned in response to any query with a matching name, unless there's a closer match from a non-wildcard record set. Azure DNS supports wildcard record sets for all record types except NS and SOA. To create a wildcard record set, use the record set name `*`.

You can create such records via portal, or powershell, or cli, or api.

Reference:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-zones-records#wildcard-records
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-operations-recordsets-portal
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-operations-recordsets
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-operations-recordsets-cli